# Rewriting a slow SQL (sub) query in JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

So I've got massive slow SQL query and I've narrowed it down to a slow sub-query, so I want to rewrite it to a JOIN. But I'm stuck... (due to the `MAX` and `GROUP BY`)

```
SELECT *
FROM local.advice AS aa
  LEFT JOIN webdb.account AS oa ON oa.shortname = aa.shortname 
WHERE aa.aa_id = ANY (SELECT MAX(dup.aa_id)
                      FROM local.advice AS dup
                      GROUP BY dup.shortname) 
  AND oa.cat LIKE '111'
ORDER BY aa.ram, aa.cpu DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: The oa.cat LIKE '111' in the WHERE clause makes the LEFT JOIN to execute as a regular inner join. If you really want a left join, move that condition to the ON clause instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info but could you write this as an answer to my question so it's more clear? Thanks in advance!

Comment: But it's not an answer to your question, that's another issue. Do you know if you want a left join or an inner join?

Comment: LEFT join of the local.advice table because I need the record with the MAX ID of every record with a unique shortname. then I join the webdb with this table to get more information about that shortname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different version of your query where the subquery is converted with a join clause

```
select * from local.advice aa 
JOIN webdb.account oa ON oa.shortname = aa.shortname 
join(
 select max(aa_id) as aa_id,shortname from local.advice 
 group by shortname
)x on x.aa_id = aa.aa_id
where
oa.cat = '111'
order by aa.ram, aa.cpu DESC 
limit 0,30
```

Also you may need to apply indexes if they are not added already

```
alter table local.advice add index shortname_idx(shortname);
alter table webdb.account add index cat_shortname_idx(cat,shortname);
alter table local.advice add index ram_idx(ram);
alter table local.advice add index cpu_idx(cpu);
```

I am assuming `aa_id` is a primary key so did not add the index

Make sure to take a backup of the tables before applying the indexes

Comment: not even kidding, this one is crazy! Speeded up my query search 26x faster!

Comment: How much time does it take now ? also you can use `explain select..` to see the query health.

Comment: from 13 sec to 0.5 sec, remember that 1 tables contain 3 million records, the other 10K

Comment: `INDEX(ram, cpu)` would be better than `INDEX(ram)`; `INDEX(cpu)` is useless.  If `aa_id` is not the `PRIMARY KEY of `advice`, then it needs `INDEX(aa_id)` and `INDEX(short_name, aa_id)`.