# Increasing speed of subquery sql statement (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Is it possible to increase the speed of this sql statement?

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            time
        FROM
            log
        WHERE
            user_id = 'name'
                AND category = 'Login'
        ORDER BY time DESC
        LIMIT 1 , 1) AS login_time,
    (SELECT 
            time
        FROM
            log
        WHERE
            user_id = 'name'
                AND category = 'Logout'
                AND app = 'RES'
        ORDER BY time DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS res_logout_timea
```

Its currently taking 10-16 seconds to complete and slowing down my app, anything I can do to improve efficiency? I was thinking about left joining the same table on itself instead of using a subquery, but I wasn't able to get the syntax down. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The change made your question lack a [mcve]. Please don't remove your code. Thank you.

Comment: There are different types of subqueries; I contend that this is not a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523739/rewriting-a-slow-sql-sub-query-in-join .  (Hence my vote to reopen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even better is

```
INDEX(user_id, category, time)       -- for the 1st subquery
INDEX(user_id, category, app, time)  -- for the 2nd subquery
```

The `time` column must be last; the order of the other columns does not matter.  You might, for example, have these two

```
INDEX(user_id, category, time)       -- for the 1st subquery
INDEX(app, user_id, category, time)  -- for the 2nd subquery
```

thereby helping some other query that needs an index starting with `app`.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a look on your indexes. Probably missing : `user_id, category, app`.
Since both queries will return only one record, it should be really fast.

Basicly, indexes create a reference table pre-ordered on several fields, this help the DB the find records when you filter or order by. When you don't use them, that database is doing it on the fly, that's why you query was taking a lot of time.

Here is the official documentation from MySQL for indexes: 
[MySQL Indexes documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: It worked, thanks. Could you simply explain what adding index does or provide a useful link?